# Initialize static array using lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template in which I have a static array. I am trying to initialize the array using lambda - but I think it is not getting initialize :

```
template <class base>
A<base> A<base>::arr[SIZE] = [] () 
{
  for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    A<base>::arr[i]=A<base>();
    std::cout<<"Test"<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

I am unable to see my cout message in console when I run the executable.

How can I initialize the array using lambda functionality?

Comment: Do that even build? Can you please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You don't call the lambda, your lambda doesn't return an array, C-arrays are not copy-able.

Comment: It seems you just need `template <class base> A<base> A<base>::arr[SIZE]{};`.

Comment: If all you want to do is to default initialize all the array members, you are doing way too much work.

Comment: Yes the code compiles - but I believe that template <class base> A<base> A<base>::arr[SIZE]{}; will not initialize all member elements - how can I do that?

Comment: dont you need to capture using `[&]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called the lambda.

The lambda does not return anything, so initializing with its return value wouldn't work anyway.

Arrays cannot be returned.

Besides default initialization, an array can only be initialized with a brace-enclosed list of values (or a string literal) which is not something that can be returned from functions (including lambdas).

Your loop appears to value initialize all elements. The elements that are not listed in the brace initialization list are value initialized, so you can achieve what your loop does with an empty brace enclosed list:

```
template <class base>
A<base> A<base>::arr[SIZE] = {};
```

Comment: Thanks - but since the array it static I need to initialize all elements with some values - will - how can I do that when SIZE value is very high

Comment: @Prakash can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: All the static array elements needs to be initialized. Since the value of SIZE is 1000 I am trying to find a way that each element of the array can be initialized.

Comment: @Prakash I've shown you how to value-initialize all of the elements.

Comment: I agree - but not with NULL values - they have to be an object as requested in the original question

Comment: @Prakash There is nothing as a "NULL" objects in C++ - The code shown here will [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) every object, which is exactly what your code does (`A<base>()`). If you want to set specific value to each object, please update your question.

Comment: @Prakash elements of arrays are always objects. `A<base>` is not a pointer, so it cannot be null (although, if it is a pointer wrapper, then it could have a state that represents null).

Comment: When I initialize like A<base> A<base>::arr[1] = {A<base>()}; and make the code flow for one iteration it works fine and similarly for 2 and so on - but if I initialize they way you told it crashes - the issue is that how can I initialize a huge array?

Comment: @Prakash In general, initializing an array of 1000 elements is ok. If you have a problem, then create a [mcve] that crashes and show us.

Comment: Thanks - yes I found the issue to be somewhere else - the instruction provided by you are correct - it did initialize all array elements. Thanks.